# Multi-threading with boost unordered hash map

Tags: multithreading, boost, mutex

I have a program that reads a file line by line, hashes the line and stores it in a boost unordered hash map (as shown below). However, I have realized this piece of code is a bottleneck in my program since the file can get pretty hugh.

```
    typedef boost::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> MAP;
    MAP hash_table;

    FILE *stream = fopen(filename, "r");
    char *line;

    while(fscanf(stream, " %m[^\n]", &line) == 1)
    {

            hash_table[line].push_back(line);
    }
```

I am planning to create multiple threads, where each is responsible to read and hash a chunk of the file. I have read that boost unordered map is thread unsafe. How can I incorporate mutexes in the code below. Will I be able to lock only the bucket that's being currently modified rather than the whole hash map?

Answer (score 0):

You mention that this is a performance bottleneck for you.  Given that, I am going to give you some performance tips which are not about mutexes, as I think threading will only make things worse here.

Given that your keys and values are exactly the same (`line`), use `unordered_set` and save roughly half the storage.

You are using the special scanf format `%m`.  This dynamically allocates memory which you must free.  But you are not freeing, so you are leaking.  Moreover, it's a big waste of time to allocate during scanf then copy to a std::string which allocates again.  Better to either store what fscanf allocated directly (and free when done with the hash table).

You are hashing the entire string.  If you know something about the lines you will be reading, you can speed that up.  For example, only hash the first ten characters of each line.

Once some of these things are cleaned up, your bottleneck will likely be the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.. I have tried changing the hash table definition to boost::unordered_map<char*,char*> MAP  and computed the time taken. I have not noticed any change in the overall time taken. Do I need to specify any buffer size to the fopen method?

Comment: No, you do not need to specify a buffer size.  To know if we can make this faster, we need to know how much CPU time is being consumed vs. actual (wall) time.  If you're on *nix, run `time myprog` (myprog is of course your executable, plus any arguments it needs).  Tell  us what that says.